# Unable to pan or zoom Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am looking to use Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps in our application.
The maps displays fine and marks the location but we are unable to interact with the map. (ie. pan the map left and right or zoom in/out or play with markers)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
    Title="Pick your area"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

                <maps:Map
                    x:Name="locationMap"
                    HasScrollEnabled="True"
                    HasZoomEnabled="True"
                    HeightRequest="300"
                    MapClicked="locationMap_MapClicked"
                    MapLongClicked="locationMap_MapLongClicked"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" />
                <StackLayout
                    Margin="20,5"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label
                        Style="{StaticResource SectionHeaders}"
                        Text="Choose from saved locations:"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Picker
                        Title="Pick address"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding SavedAddresses}"
                        SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </StackLayout>


            </StackLayout>

        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The application is based on

- Xamarin Forms 4.5.0
- Xamarin Form GoogleMaps 3.3.0

It is a shell architecture.

If anyone can help us use it, it would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, turns out it was really stupid. There was an absolutely placed control of list view  that was in hidden state which prevented interaction.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, Please do not forget to mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I write `Shell` and `Xamarin Form GoogleMaps` demo to test it. Here is running GIF.

[image]

It is running normally, my nuget package version like following sceenshot.(I test it in Android 8.1 and Android 9.0, both of them are Ok)

[image]

Here is demo, you can download it and test it in your emulator, please do not forget to the change api key in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="api key" />
```

https://github.com/851265601/ShellAndGoogleMapPlugin

Comment: @parvkothari Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Sorry, turns out it was really stupid. There was an absolutely placed control that was hidden over on the map which prevented interaction.